# endless redirect on keycloak 3.1.0 with reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, spring-boot, keycloak

I am using keycloak 3.1.0 Final
I am checking the working of openid connect in keycloak. But got stuck in the middle.

Everything works fine when keycloak and spring-boot running in localhost (meaning spring-boot's auth-server-url = localhost:8080/auth and redirect url etc in keycloak also are pointing to localhost* ). Now I wanted to check by putting both of them behind Reverse proxy server (Nginx)

I am starting keycloak in standalone mode using the command:

```
bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0
```

I have a simple spring boot application with the application.properties file as something like this:

```
server.port = 8001

keycloak.auth-server-url=http://myserver.com/auth
keycloak.realm=myrealm
keycloak.resource=web-app

keycloak.ssl-required=none
keycloak.credentials.secret=aaaaa-bbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeee
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
```

In Keycloak I created a realm **myrealm** with a client called **web-app**

I wanted to work with http only (no https).

Most of the are default. The only things which are worth mentioning are :

- **Require SSL** in realm settings to **None**.
- **access type** in client is set to confidential
- **client protocol** is openid connect
- **redirect uri** is http://myserver.com/myapp
- **client authenticator** is based on clientID and secret.

On the Nginx side I have a simple conf file:

Please note I am setting the **$Host** to **$host/myapp**. otherwise keycloak was not able to get redirect properly to myapp.

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myserver.com;

   location /myapp {
        proxy_set_header        Host               $host/myapp;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Port   80;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto  http;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8001/;

    }

   location /auth {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

So far I am able to see the login page of keycloak. I enter user name and password. Then in the browser I see several redirects happening.

spring boot logs say **No State cookie**

I see the following network calls going on in a loop until the browser stops eventually.

```
/auth/realms/myrealm/login-actions/authenticate?code=o2M-zFsbBdHYx1VTacW9JANrsLHM3S1DIF6Geg4mn3E.27593a49-58c6-4217-9c4c-da1e95c2b97c&execution=10865b14-0a24-4eee-b93c-df811d2ddb51

/myapp/sso/login?state=d61d9b7e-a872-443a-8718-2345f29905ad&code=oe8vgQf7URXcHvQtCw1HVJN5mCGEsBgfcVK9AaErKY4.27593a49-58c6-4217-9c4c-da1e95c2b97c

/myapp/sso/login
```

Can anyone please guide me on what am I missing.

Comment: I cross checked if keycloak.credentials.secret has any typos. earlier when there was a mismatch the same endless redirect started happening. But this time it is the same. still no luck

Comment: see the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799864/reverse-proxy-configuration-for-keycloak-nginx for a workaround